# Displaying Multiple CheckBox in php

Tags: checkbox, multiple-select

Now, What i want to do is check any two or three checkboxes and after redirecting to multichk.php page, checked boxes should be shown.

```
<?php

?>
<html>
    <form method="post" name="Myf" action="multichk.php">
        C <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="C" ><br>
        C++ <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="C++" ><br>
        Java <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="Java" ><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </html>
```

These two are separate files.

```
<?php

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if(isset($_POST['check_b']))
      { 

        foreach($_POST['check_b'] as $ch)
        {
        ?>
        C <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="C" <?php if($ch=="C"){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?> ><br>
        C++ <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="C++" <?php if($ch=="C++"){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?> ><br>
        Java <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="Java" <?php if($ch=="Java"){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?> ><br>
       <?php

        }

      }
    }       
       ?>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are use html form tag same as in your first file if we checked more then one check box and then we click the submit then automatically redirect to the form action file.

and in your 2nd file there use form tag without action part.

Answer (score 0):

change second file code to following one

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<?php
$checked = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['check_b']))
    {  
        foreach($_POST['check_b'] as $ch)
        {
            $checked[] = $ch;
        }
    }
}       

?>
C <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="C" <?php if(in_array("C", $checked)){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?> ><br>
C++ <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="C++" <?php if(in_array("C++", $checked)){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?> ><br>
Java <input type="checkbox" name="check_b[]" value="Java" <?php if(in_array("Java", $checked)){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?> ><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Just one suggestion, If you see code, You may realize that their are no need to use two separate files at all, you can send form action to same file :)